# Working with JSON via GET requests in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, get

I've built a php API that provides data in json output, I need to get the values via a get request to then plot as a graph on the page.

The front end web component in hosted on the same server as in the api in this basic structure:

- index.php
- graph.php
- /api/
- /api/src
- /api/src/api.php

My current code in graph.php is as follows:

```
<script>
        var myJson;

        $.getJson('api/src/api.php/poll/results/current/13/', function(jd){
          myJson = jd.AnswerCount.1;
        });

        document.getElementById('jsonhere').innerHTML = myJson; //just to test
</script>
```

The endpoint outputs data like the following:

```
{"AnswerCount":{"1":5,"3":1,"2":2,"4":1,"5":5,"6":3,"7":2}}
```

Which I need loaded into a key-value pair array,

```
1:5
3:1
2:2
4:1
...
```

to then be put into the graphing library.

How do I fix my code/write new code to do this? I'm pretty stuck here.

EDIT:

On a hunch I logged all the get requests via wireshark, and no request is ever sent to the url in question. Even with an empty function { } ? http://grab.kfouwels.com/pmgW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can't use a number as an identifier, to access the `1` property you have to say `[1]` not `.1`
2. You have to use the variable containing your data, not `x` which hasn't been mentioned until you try to assign it somewhere
3. The A in Ajax stands for Asynchronous. You have to work with your data **inside your callback** since the function you pass to `getJson` won't be called until the HTTP response arrived but the line starting `document.get` will run as soon as the HTTP request has been sent.

Comment: I tried the above, and still nothing. Looking at the packet transmissions via wireshark, no get request is ever sent to the GET url in question? Even with an empty function { } in the .getJson http://grab.kfouwels.com/pmgW

Comment: None at all, which is the odd thing